# How to query part of a field in Lucene.NET

Tags: c#, lucene.net, querying

Say I have an index containing a collection of Users, storing their full name in a Name field. Some of these users are of the format "Firstname Lastname", and some are "Firstname Middlename(s) Lastname"

e.g.

1. Joe Bloggs
2. Joe Fred Bloggs
3. Joe John Paul Bloggs

If I search for "Joe Bloggs", I need it to return all users listed above.

I've tried using a PhraseQuery , but this will only return 'Joe Bloggs' (I presume due to terms needing to be in the correct order).

Is my only option to use a WildcardQuery? I wouldn't want 'Joe Smith' or 'John Bloggs' to be returned. Also, I can't rework the index to split the full name into separate fields.

How best should I form my query to get things to work as required?

Thanks

Comment: Why would "Joe Smith" be returned if you search for `Joe *Bloggs`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm thinking more along the lines of  Joe* Bloggs. Either way, I'm not sure Joe *Bloggs would work.  Say you were searching for "Joe *Bloggs"  and someone was called "Joe Bigbloggs", we don't want him appearing in the results.

Comment: That's kind of why I picked `Joe *Bloggs`, because `Joe* Bloggs` would also find `Joey Bloggs` and I considered the likelihood of a last name with an unexpected prefix smaller than that of a first name with an unexpected suffix, and if Lucene can be configured to search in a case-sensitive manner (I don't know if it can), you'd only be worried about `Joe McBloggs` showing up, not `Joe Bigbloggs`. But you're right that no wildcard query would work fully correctly here, if whitespace is significant. (You could always do some post-filtering on "mostly correct" results.)

Comment: Or, you could use a `BooleanQuery` where you `OR` together the wildcard queries `Joe Bloggs` and `Joe * Bloggs`. No idea as to efficiency, but it should find only exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take care which analyzer you use.

You probably just want "whitespace" to break words at ws. Plus "lower case" so that "fred" matches "Fred"

2. You query should simply be "name:joe AND name:bloggs" (or the equivalent if you are constructing your query objects manually)

This says that the name field MUST contain both words